# Why is just reading a small file taking so long?

Tags: java, performance, file-io

I'm doing what seems like a simple read from a data file, and it's taking for fricking ever. (And by that, I mean 300ms.) This is the code in question:

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
int var1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())
int var2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
Integer[][] people = new Integer[var1][];
for(int i = 0; i < var2; i++)
    f.readLine();
for(Integer i = 0; i < var1; i++)
{
    StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine(), " \t\n\r\f,");
    line.nextToken();
    Integer[] list = new Integer[line.countTokens()];
    for(int j = 0; j < drinks.length; j++)
        list[j] = Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken());
    people[i] = list;
}
```

And this is the relevant `time` output:

```
sammysmbp:fridgemadness_lean sfishman$ time java fridgemadness

real    0m0.311s
user    0m0.277s
sys  0m0.056s
```

Is it just me or is that really, really slow. It's only going through 51 lines of input in this example.

Comment: That depends on the input file. How big is it?

Comment: @dark_charlie "51 lines of input"

Comment: Have you tried measuring the time within your app? Then you'd be ignoring the java runtime startup cost. "java -version" takes 0.1s on my machine.

Comment: The JRE needs some "warm-up" time. Increase the number of lines by a factor 10 and you'll see that the run-time of your app does not increase by that same factor.

Comment: @Michael, the lines could by very long...

Comment: Try running that whole code in a cycle thousands of times and look at the time. That long time is probably just the JVM startup time.

Comment: @vanza just did that and you guys were all correct... that block completes in 1ms.

Comment: You may also want to change the reference to 'drinks', I think you mean to use 'list' there instead.

Comment: @jex haha, I was just trying to mask what the actual function of the code is. All my references are correct in the actual code.

Comment: @Bart K. @dark_charlie, The lines are fairly short. 30 characters or so each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, but probably a lot of the time is used up just for the jvm to start up.

Print a timestamp just before and after the relevant code. If my guess is correct a little server taking requests might help to eliminate the startup time.

Comment: Thanks. Just timed it within the program itself, and it completes in 1ms. All the other time is spent in the system apparently.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need \r or \n in the pattern, readLine() has already removed them.

JVM startup aside, most of the time will be spent in reading to the desired position if the file is at all long. Maybe a text file of lines isn't the correct data structure.